# Unable to copy data from column to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA, trying to write some code that will copy all data except for header from a column in source workbook and paste in a different column with header in another workbook.

I can currently get it to copy the first cell only. I have read through so many things but everything I try is resulting in errors

```
Dim details As Variant, mydata As Workbook

Details = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("N")

Set mydata = Workbooks.Open("C:\desktop\book2.xlsx")

RowCount = mydata.Worksheets("Template").Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
mydata.Worksheets("template").Range("B" & RowCount) = YourRef
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Details = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("N")
```

There is no `Range("N")` in VBA. You might mean `Range("N:N")` but if you want to offset one row down to exclude the header row, you cannot use a full column reference. Essentially, the one row offset would be attempting to push the full column off of the bottom of the worksheet.

```
with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
  Details = .range(.cells(2, "N"), .cells(.rows.count, "N").end(xlup)).value
end with
```

The above collect the values from column N starting in row 2 down to the last value in column N,

You need to locate the last cell with data in column B of `Worksheets("Template")` then offset one row down and resize your target according to the size of the variant array you used to collect the source data.

```
Dim details As Variant, mydata As Workbook

with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
  Details = .range(.cells(2, "N"), .cells(.rows.count, "N").end(xlup)).value
end with

Set mydata = Workbooks.Open("C:\desktop\book2.xlsx")

with mydata.Worksheets("template")
  .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).resize(ubound(details, 1), ubound(details, 2)) = Details
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have no data in target workbook aside from headers to columns. Still not copying data across though.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you substituted `YourRef` for `details`. I've made the edit above.